# Background image fade in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, background, jquery-animate, fade

I'm tryin to do fade backgrounds in jQuery and CSS, this is my code - but its not working. Any ideas?

```
var images = ['bg.jpg', '_4.jpg', '_5.jpg', '_6.jpg'];
var i = 0;

setInterval(function(){
$('body').animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {
        $(this)
            .css('background-image', function() {
        if (i >= images.length) {
            i=0;
        }
        return 'url(' + images[i++] + ')'; 
    });
            .animate({opacity: 1});
    });
}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: You realize you can't really animate the background images opacity, but only the elements themselves.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fading in background image with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690869/fading-in-background-image-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can animate background-color, but not background-images, I beat my head against this wall too.

See here- [Fade in new background images on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526944/fade-in-new-background-images-on-scroll)

As in the answer to my question you need to use `<img>`'s with a negative z-index and fade those in.

This how I did it-

CSS

```
#img1, #img2, #img3, #img4 {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 150) {
        $('#img2').fadeIn();
    }
    else {$('#img2').fadeOut('fast')};

    if (y > 300) {
        $('#img3').fadeIn();
    }
    else {$('#img3').fadeOut('fast')};

    if (y > 450) {
        $('#img4').fadeIn();
    }
    else {$('#img4').fadeOut('fast')};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function(){
            $('.light').animate({opacity: 0}, 4000, function() {
                $('.light').css({background:'url(./images/' + images[i++] + ') no-repeat top center'}).animate({opacity: 1},4000);
                if (i >= images.length) { i=0; }
            });
        }, 4000);
```

this one must work i try this on div